# Android: Prevent Clipboard Copy of Text

Tags: java, android, clipboard

Our application requires that the text displayed in TextViews or WebViews is not copyable. Can we disable the copy function for controls in an activity or application?

Comment: Sorry, i was meaning `OnLongClickListener`

Comment: @Nikola, I am not sure but what if other view needs onLongClickListener, Do you recon it will affect other views as well by overriding that method?

Comment: @krio, if you add that listener on the TextView, only on that view `onLCL()` will be envoked...

Comment: Ohh yeah thats true! Sorry my bad, However could you please check my answer. which one is better?

Comment: @krio Yes, thats another way. With this you are not doing calls on the oLCL() at all. :) I always do the hardway :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this on TextViews, This mechanism is same in WebView as well.

```
textView.cancelLongPress();
webView.cancelLongPress();
```

This should work, as user will not be able to trigger onLongClickListner. Hope this will help to achieve in shortest possible code.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

The copy/paste/select..etc dialog shows up when you do long press on the text area. What if you override `onLongClickListener` for your view and do nothing inside? Or use `ClipboardManager` and listen for primary clip changes, if the changes occur then check if there is text or anything else, if true then use `setPrimaryClip()` with `ClipData` instance that contains let say empty string. This not might be the best approach, but these pointers maybe will give you the idea.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipData.html

Answer (score 0):

The below worked for me:

```
textView.setLongClickable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason none of the other answers worked for me so here is my take on it. I specifically used it on a Webview :

```
webview.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {

            public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                menu.clear();

            }
        });
```

Hope it helps someone.